# Trying to set td text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why is my jquery not setting the td?

```
$("td")[0].text("hello");
```

Find preceding below:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var counter = 0;
while( array.length ) {
    var index = Math.floor( Math.random()*array.length );
    //alert( array[index] ); // Log the item
    //$('td').index(counter).html(index);
    $("td")[0].text("hello");
    array.splice( index, 1 ); // Remove the item from the array
    counter++;
    //alert(array);
}
```

JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/o3c66fz8/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `$("td").eq(0).text("hello");` instead.

```js
 var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
    var counter = 0;
    while( array.length ) {
          var index = Math.floor( Math.random()*array.length );
        //alert( array[index] ); // Log the item
        //$('td').index(counter).html(index);
        $("td").eq(index).text("hello");
        array.splice( index, 1 ); // Remove the item from the array
        counter++;
        //alert(array);
    }
```

```css
td
{
padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>r1c1</td><td>r1c2</td><td>r1c3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>r2c1</td><td>r2c2</td><td>r3c3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

By using `[0]` you are changing it to a regular JavaScript element and thus losing the jQuery functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use td:first to get the first td

```js
 var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
    var counter = 0;
    while( array.length ) {
          var index = Math.floor( Math.random()*array.length );
        //alert( array[index] ); // Log the item
        //$('td').index(counter).html(index);
        $("td:first").text("hello");
        array.splice( index, 1 ); // Remove the item from the array
        counter++;
        //alert(array);
    }
```

```css
td
{
padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>r1c1</td><td>r1c2</td><td>r1c3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>r2c1</td><td>r2c2</td><td>r3c3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```